# How to remove red background on MultiValueRemove when focused

Tags: react-select

I want to style the `MultiValueRemove` container when it is focused (the one with the x inside to remove the chosen value). The `backgroundColor` changes to a red I don't want to have.

I can style the background when it is neither focused nor selected, but the "onHover" red background remains unaffected. Styling the background with the state `isSelected`, `isFocused` does not affect the red background when I hover on it.

```
multiValueRemove: (provided, state) => ({
  ...provided,
  color: '#ffffff',
  backgroundColor: '#6FC5C4',
  borderRadius: 0,
}),
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a trick for this one, `isSelected` and `isFocused` don't work in this case but you can use regular `css` hover state like this:

```
 multiValueRemove: (base, state) => ({
    ...base,
    color: "#fff",
    backgroundColor: "#6FC5C4",
    borderRadius: 0,
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#6FC5C4",
      color: "#fff"
    }
  })
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work when the remove component is "selected" by hitting the left arrow.